# Create vector for each column of a matrix and also construct the matrix but with that column removed

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, neural-network

I've imported some data from a CSV file in matlab. They are time series that are all aligned (the fact that they are time series is not important, just that each column represents a single entity, and the rows are observations for that entity). This give me say, a 2500x50 matrix of doubles called `data` and a 1x50 cell array called `colheaders`.

What I am trying to do is use the Neural Network toolset to predict each entity (i.e., column) from all the others. The Neural Network tool takes as input a "target" (a single column of the matrix) and "input" (the original matrix but with the same column used as "target" removed from the matrix).

Suppose the entries in `colheaders` are of the form Col1, Col2, Col3, etc. I'd like to automate the process of training the model and making predictions for each column of the original matrix so that I have as output a bunch of prediction columns labeled Predicted_Col1, Predicted_Col2, etc.

I think I can figure out the Neural Network part but I just don't know how to begin on the matrix manipulation and cross-referencing to the `colheaders` array. This seems like a common thing to want to do so I am guessing that someone knows an easy, straight-forward way to do it that is computationally efficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming *colheaders* is a cell of strings and *data* is your 2500x50 input array, the code below goes through all columns of *data*, separates target from input, feeds it into a pseudo-code for NN, and gradually builds the predicted matrix while creating custom column headers separately in out_colheaders:

```
predicted = zeros(size(data));
for i = 1:size(data, 2)
    target = data(:, i);
    training_input = data;
    training_input(:, i) = [];
    // assuming the following function returns a column of 2500x1
    // given training_input of size 2500x49 and target 2500x1
    predicted(:, i) = pseudo_neural(training_input, target);
    out_colheaders{i} = ['Predicted_' colheaders{i}];
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I solved it myself slightly differently, but I like your solution better. I basically took each column of the input matrix and subtracted it, leaving a column of all zeros in the matrix, which I then save as a new variable. Thanks again for the help.